# Difference between editor.addAction() and editor.addCommand() and their use case in Monaco Editor

Tags: difference, monaco-editor

I am new to Monaco Editor, and found two examples on the official website playground:

- [Adding a command to an editor instance](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#interacting-with-the-editor-adding-a-command-to-an-editor-instance)
- [Adding an action to an editor instance](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#interacting-with-the-editor-adding-an-action-to-an-editor-instance)

After checking the code i am a little bit confuse, seems like `an action` is the advanced version of `a command`? The `addCommand()` only supports a shortcut to trigger it, while the `addAction()` can trigger it with shortcut, right click menu and command palette.

**So what is the use case of using `addCommand()` and `addAction()`?** To me, they have some functionality overlapped.

Comment: I believe commands existed before actions and cannot be removed without breaking compatibility. Actions provide enhance functionality compared to commands.

Comment: @MikeLischke So action is like pro version of command?

Comment: That's my assumption, yes.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65399399/monaco-editor-difference-between-action-and-command