# Monaco Editor - Difference between `Action` and `Command`?

Tags: monaco-editor

In a monaco [editor instance](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.istandalonecodeeditor.html), you can call [`addAction`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.istandalonecodeeditor.html#addaction) or[`addCommand`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.istandalonecodeeditor.html#addcommand)

Both provide the ability to execute a function based on key events

The online playground offers examples of how to [add a command](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#interacting-with-the-editor-adding-a-command-to-an-editor-instance) or how to [add an action](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#interacting-with-the-editor-adding-an-action-to-an-editor-instance) to an editor instance.

**Example of an Action**

```js
editor.addAction({
    id: 'my-unique-id',
    label: 'My Label!!!',
    keybindings: [monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd | monaco.KeyCode.Enter],
    run: function() { alert('action called') }
});
```

**Example of a Command**

```js
editor.addCommand(
  monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd | monaco.KeyCode.Enter,
  function() { alert('called command') }
)
```

The documentation describes the type definitions, properties, and methods.

However, it's lacking when it comes to providing the context of when to use each, where they show up within the editor, and what each provides.

What's the difference between actions and commands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My personal impression is that actions are kinda evolved commands. Commands have been introduced first and later it was recognized that more functionality was needed (e.g. context menu integration), so `Action` was created. For compatibility reasons `Command` could not be removed by then, so both still exist today.

Comment: I generally agree, but I found a strange edge case. It seems that if you have multiple editors on the page, `addCommand` doesn't work properly - it triggers events from the wrong editor. Switching to `addAction` solved the problem for me.

Comment: One more indication that actions are the better commands :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are some key differences between `Action` and `Command`:

- `Action` is editor-specific. You add an action with the `addAction` method of `monaco.editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor`. `Command` can be added with the `addCommand` method of `IStandaloneCodeEditor` which makes it editor-specific too (the added command is **anonymous** and can only be triggered by a key binding); however, there is another (more common) way to register a command: via the global `monaco.editor.registerCommand` function. This way you can register a **named command** for **all** the editors;
- `Action` appears and can be triggered from the command palette (F1 in monaco editor, or Ctrl+Shift+P in vscode), while `Command` does not (despite it being called a *command palette*);
- Some language providers, such as `monaco.languages.CodeActionProvider`, can only utilize `Command`s. E.g. to provide a custom refactor feature, you have to register a `Command` and provide it in the `CodeActionProvider` to make it appear in the refactor menu.

Therefore `Action` and `Command` are different abstractions, one does not replace another.